# PHP : Echo error,undefined blank page

Tags: php, undefined

I'm trying to echo and print out some variables and a few arrays. However, every time I try all that came up is 'Undefined'. I research but most are not relevant to my problem. Instead of showing error,a blank page with only the word 'undefined' is shown. I isset my variables and all, so i know it is not that. Please help me,is there any other way for me to print out?

```
    <?PHP 

    session_start();

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['name'];
        $name = $_SESSION['username'];


        $namesql = "SELECT student_id FROM student_profile WHERE name='$name'";
        $nameQuer = mysql_query($namesql);
        $nameArr = mysql_fetch_assoc($nameQuer);
        $student_id = $nameArr['student_id'];
        //echo $student_id;
    }


    $store = array();
    if (isset($_POST['question_id'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['question_id'] as $key => $option) {
            //echo $key;
//            echo $option;

            $option1 = array_filter($option);
            print_r($option1);


            if (count($option1) > 1) {
                $option2 = implode("^", $option1);
                $store[] = $option2;
                // echo 'Option Mult Selected';
                //print($option2);
            } else {
                $value = $option1;

                $i = implode(null, $option1);
                // echo '<br />';
                // echo 'Option Single Selected';
                // echo $i;
                //print_r($value);
                //  echo'<br />';
                $store[] = $i;
            }
            //  echo '<br />';
        }
           print_r($store);
    }

    $t = new DateTime();
    $t->setTimestamp($time = time());
    $t->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    // print $t->format(DateTime::RFC850);
    $date = $t->format(DateTime::RFC850);



}
?>
```

Comment: Is your code also `undefined`? if not, can we see?

Comment: i edited to insert my codes...

Comment: Seems like your query is returning 0 results.

Comment: Obligatory comment about potential for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)